# My font size set using openXML for a Powerpoint paragraph is not being used

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml

I'm trying to set a font size for a paragraph in a PowerPoint slide. In my code when I print out the font size it displays as 9 but when I open up my PowerPoint it is set to 12.

Notes:

- I don't have admin rights on my pc so I can't install tools to help reverse-engineer something as I've read in a few posts.
- `_bulletParagraphOuterXML` is a string I grabbed from a premade paragraph after hours of hunting how to set bullets via code. Still don't know how and learning how is another post for the future. Even if it says Arial in this string the bullet point text is in Times New Roman.
- In the code it prints a font size of 9 but in the PowerPoint it shows up with a font size of 12.

Bellow is code I've extracted from the class I use to modify and update my PowerPoint Document.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using D = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;
using P = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;

static string _bulletParagraphOuterXML = "<a:pPr marL=\"285750\" indent=\"-285750\" xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\"><a:buFont typeface=\"Arial\" panose=\"020B0604020202020204\" pitchFamily=\"34\" charset=\"0\" /><a:buChar char=\"•\" /></a:pPr>";


public static void ReplaceShapeBulletsText(this SlidePart slidePart, string ShapeName, List<string> newTexts)
    {
        P.Shape shape = slidePart.GetShapeByName(ShapeName);

        D.Paragraph paragraph = shape.TextBody.Elements<D.Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();
        shape.TextBody.RemoveAllChildren<D.Paragraph>();

        foreach (string text in newTexts)
        {
            shape.AddBulletParagraph(text);
        }
    }


    public static void AddBulletParagraph(this P.Shape shape, string NewText)
    {

        D.Paragraph p = new D.Paragraph();

        P.TextBody docBody = shape.TextBody;
        p.ParagraphProperties = new D.ParagraphProperties(_bulletParagraphOuterXML);
        D.Run run = new D.Run(new D.Text(NewText));
        D.RunProperties runProp = new D.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 9, Dirty = false };
        run.AppendChild(runProp);
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine(runProp.FontSize.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------");
        p.Append(run);
        docBody.Append(p);

    }
```

Comment: What do you see if you crack open the XML of the resulting file? If run properties read like this: <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0"/>, the slide master and layout are controlling the text size. If run properties look like this: <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="900" dirty="0"/>, you've set the size correctly, but the slide may need to be reset (Home>Reset) to update it's appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Order of appending matters in openXML. After being able to get both the text with the incorrect font size and the text with the correct font size to appear in the same shape I noticed only one difference.

The order in which `a:rPr` and `a:t` appear. `a:rPr` needs to precede `a:t`

Knowing this one fact should also help me solve lots of other issues I've been having.

Correct Font Size

```
<a:p>

    <a:pPr marL="171450" indent="-171450">

        <a:buFont typeface="Arial" charset="0" pitchFamily="34" panose="020B0604020202020204"/>    
        <a:buChar char="•"/>

    </a:pPr>
    <a:r>

        <a:rPr lang="en-US" sz="900"/>
        <a:t>Random Text</a:t>

    </a:r>
    <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" sz="900"/>

</a:p>
```

Incorrect Font Size

```
<a:p>

    <a:pPr xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" marL="285750" indent="-285750">

        <a:buFont typeface="Arial" charset="0" pitchFamily="34" panose="020B0604020202020204"/>
        <a:buChar char="•"/>

    </a:pPr>
    <a:r>

        <a:t>Other Random Text</a:t>
        <a:rPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" sz="900"/>

    </a:r>
    <a:endParaRPr lang="en-US" dirty="0" sz="900"/>

</a:p>
```

To relate it back to my code.

This code block:

```
    p.ParagraphProperties = new D.ParagraphProperties(_bulletParagraphOuterXML);
    D.Run run = new D.Run(new D.Text(NewText));
    D.RunProperties runProp = new D.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 9, Dirty = false };
    run.AppendChild(runProp);
```

was updated to

```
    p.ParagraphProperties = new D.ParagraphProperties(_bulletParagraphOuterXML);
    D.Run run = new D.Run();
    D.RunProperties runProp = new D.RunProperties() { Language = "en-US", FontSize = 900, Dirty = false  };
    run.AppendChild(runProp);
    D.Text newText = new D.Text(NewText);
    run.AppendChild(newText);
```